# Proper use libdl and dynamically linked libraries

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries

I need to dynamically link a library that I have created.  I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.  It all compiles properly, but I always catch `handle` as the `NULL` pointer:

```
void *handle;
char *error;
handle = dlopen ("./hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so", RTLD_LAZY);
//same error comes up with full path as well as './hw11...'
if(!handle){
    error = dlerror();
    printf("%s\n", error);
    printf("Error loading library.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

I cant get passed this error and I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong. I'm pretty sure I've compiled everything correctly.  Here are the compilation steps I used:

```
gcc -rdynamic -c hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.c -o hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so
gcc hw11-michaelSchilling-4.c -ldl -o hw11-michaelSchilling-4
```

I'm getting an error that reads

> only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When building `hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so`, you don't appear to be telling `gcc` that you want a shared object (the `.so` in the name isn't enough).

With the `-c` it's producing an object file (not a *shared* object) and calling it `michaelSchilling.so`. The linker doesn't even get invoked.

Remove the `-c` from the `gcc` command line and add `-shared`:

```
gcc -shared -rdynamic hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.c -o hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so
```

Comment: Along with `-rdynamic`?  Just tried it with both and with just `-shared`, but I got the same error.

Comment: @MichaelSchilling: I don't think `-rdynamic` has anything to do with the problem, so you might as well keep it in case it is needed by your code.

Comment: @MichaelSchilling: Have you removed the `-c`?

Answer (score 1):

A slash (`/`) as the first character of a pathname indicates that the pathname is absolute (relative to the root directory), not relative to the current working directory and certainly not relative to the location of the binary. You'll need to specify the full path by figuring out the location of the binary (which is not an easy problem in itself) or you might be able to use `$ORIGIN` with `dlopen` (it works with rpath but I'm uncertain whether it works with `dlopen`).

Comment: What about a period before the path? (`./`)

Comment: That makes it relative to the current working directory, not the location of your program binary.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -rdynamic  library.c -o library.o
```

works for me on Linux when compiling the library
for the code that opens it, you need `-ldl`

Answer (score 0):

Is `hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so` in the absolute root of your file system? You're claiming it is by leading a slash on it... but I suspect it's not.

In your error handling, include the output of `dlerror()` in what you print, to find the cause of failure.

Comment: hw11-lib-michaelSchilling.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Thats the error I get, but its the same directory as the program I'm trying to run.
I also removed the slash.

Comment: Try providing the full absolute path to the shared object to see if that helps.

Comment: I did, and I got `only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded.`